# Blank screen after posting comments in Stack Overflow mobile app

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app

[image: Screenshot of application showing a blank screen, with a hand-drawn red circle to highlight the blankness of the screen.]

A blank screen is displayed after entering a comment in the Stack Overflow mobile app. Now I do not know whether the comment was submitted successfully.

Comment: Reproduced (iOS 11.3.1, iPhone 8, Stack Exchange App version 1.6.6.2)

Comment: @JustaStudent, that was one smart edit!